# Why doesn't the rowcreated event fire after sorting my gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

At the moment I have a gridview that's bound to a collection. Within the 'RowCreated' event I'm manipulating the html (adding strikethroughs to certain fields).

This all works fine on page load but whenever I sort a column the RowCreated event doesn't seem to be firing.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Here's what I'm doing in my RowCreated method..

```
protected void gvResults_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
                {
                    Property currentProperty = (Property)e.Row.DataItem;

                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", currentProperty.Id.ToString());

                    Document propertyDoc = new Document(currentProperty.Id);

                    if (currentProperty.Price == 0)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Clear();
                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "N/A" });
                    }
                    if (propertyDoc.getProperty("floorPlan").Value == null || propertyDoc.getProperty("floorPlan").Value.ToString() == "")
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Clear();
                        e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "View" });
                    }
                    if (propertyDoc.getProperty("propertyImage").Value == null || propertyDoc.getProperty("propertyImage").Value.ToString() == "")
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Clear();
                        e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "View" });
                    }

                    if (currentProperty.Reserved == true)
                    {
                        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#999999");
                        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = currentProperty.DevelopmentName;
                        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = currentProperty.LocationDisplayText;
                        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = currentProperty.PropertyTypeName;
                        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = currentProperty.BedroomsDisplayText;

                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Clear();
                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "RESERVED" });
                        //e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Clear();
                        //e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<del>View</del>" });
                        //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Clear();
                        //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<del>View</del>" });
                    }
                    else if (currentProperty.Sold == true)
                    {
                        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#999999");
                        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = currentProperty.DevelopmentName;
                        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = currentProperty.LocationDisplayText;
                        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = currentProperty.PropertyTypeName;
                        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = currentProperty.BedroomsDisplayText;

                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Clear();
                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "SOLD" });
                        //e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Clear();
                        //e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<del>View</del>" });
                        //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Clear();
                        //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<del>View</del>" });
                    }
                    else if (currentProperty.Released == true)
                    {
                        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#999999");
                        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = currentProperty.DevelopmentName;
                        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = currentProperty.LocationDisplayText;
                        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = currentProperty.PropertyTypeName;
                        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = currentProperty.BedroomsDisplayText;

                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Clear();
                        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "TO BE RELEASED" });
                        //e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Clear();
                        //e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<del>View</del>" });
                        //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Clear();
                        //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<del>View</del>" });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the front end code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FullSearchResults.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyControls.FullSearchResults" %>
<div id="search-results">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="odsProperties"
        AllowSorting="true" Width="700px" OnRowCommand="gvResults_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="gvResults_RowCreated">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-header" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#e6e6e6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Plot" HeaderText="Plot" SortExpression="Plot" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Development" SortExpression="Development">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("DevelopmentName").ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("LocationDisplayText").ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("PropertyTypeName").ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Beds" SortExpression="Bedrooms">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("BedroomsDisplayText").ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("PriceDisplayText").ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plans">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewFloorplans" runat="server" CommandName="View" Text="View"
                        CommandArgument='<%# (int)Eval("Id") %>' CssClass="view-floorplan" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewImage" runat="server" CommandName="View" Text="View"
                        CommandArgument='<%# (int)Eval("Id") %>' CssClass="view-floorplan" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProperties" runat="server" TypeName="MyControls.DataAccess"
        SelectMethod="GetSearchResultsForAllDevelopments" SortParameterName="_sortExpression">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="_county" QueryStringField="loc" Type="Int16" DefaultValue="-1" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="_bedrooms" QueryStringField="rooms" Type="Int16"
                DefaultValue="-1" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="_price" QueryStringField="price" Type="Int16" DefaultValue="-1" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="_propertyType" QueryStringField="type" Type="Int16"
                DefaultValue="-1" />            
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>    
</div>
```

Comment: `RowCreated` is triggered every time. So you need to show us some code.

Comment: Do you have client-side sorting? Because, as Tim said, `RowCreated` fires every post back.

Comment: But if it's firing every postback then surely my code should be getting executed? At the moment it doesn't seem to be

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `RowDataBound` event instead of the `RowCreated` event to perform your HTML customizations (i.e. adding strike-through to certain fields).

The `RowDataBound` event will be called whenever the grid view is rebound (i.e. `GridView.DataBind()` is called). The `RowDataBound` event also has access to the actual data being rendered in the row, so it is generally what people want to do, because most row alterations are relative to the data contained in that row.

---

> `RowCreated` is primarily concerned with building the structure (i.e. controls defined in the markup of the grid) of the row and is fired on page `Init` and post backs.

---

> `RowDataBound` is primary concerned with binding the data from the data source into the controls created in the `RowCreated` event.

Comment: Thanks Karl but I did actually try this already - it didn't work. I wonder if any of this could be related to the fact I'm using an object data source too?